# Âncora de LINK para Seção Não Funciona no FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('a.scroll').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    if (id.match('^#')) {

      var target = $(id).offset().top - 65;
      var title = $(this).attr('title');

      $(this).on('click tap', function() {
        $('body').animate({
          scrollTop: target
        }, 1000);
        history.pushState({
          foo: title
        }, title, id);
        return false;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

### Mesma Página

```
<a href="pecas-servicos#qualidade" class="scroll" title="{!! trans('master.menu.qualidade')">Qualidade</a>
```

### Outra Página

```
<a href="pecas-servicos/contato#qualidade" class="scroll" title="{!! trans('master.menu.qualidade')">Qualidade</a>
```

Quando estou na página HOME e clico no LINK funciona a rolagem até a seção que cliquei.

Mas se estou em outra página o mesmo não acontece. Ele até vai para a HOME, porém, desce até o **bottom** da página.

Comment: essas outras páginas são carregadas dentro da home ?

Comment: Não. Outras páginas independentes.

Comment: dê uma olhada vê se isso pode lhe ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163615/how-to-scroll-html-page-to-given-anchor-using-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: Não funciona assim. Ele vai para o bottom da página também. Mas se eu dou um enter na barra de endereços ele vai para a sessão certa... não dá pra entender.

Comment: Não sei se já resolveu e eu sei que não tem haver com o problema, mas porque esperar o `.load` ao invés do `$.ready`?

Comment: Mano, que bagulho desnecessário ficar corrigindo UpperCase ou LowerCase nos Posts de 1930...

Comment: Se está falando sobre URL AMIGÁVEL? tem mexer seu htaccess (existe 3 linguagens independente do servidor de hospedagem) para encaminhar certinho do site ... ou já utilizou <NAME>? e veja http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ele não reconhece o post via Script estranho não funcionar somente no Firefox. Duas coisas que eu tentaria.

1. Colocar a URL Completa segue um teste que coloquei no meu site ( http://papoinformal.com.br/teste/anchor.html );
2. Forçar a URL pegando o parametro e encontrar a parte correta da página assim ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery );

Fala depois se alguma delas funcionou.

Comment: Nenhuma funcionou.

Comment: Testei o code em duas versões diferentes de Firefox e funcionou normalmente. Mas você está usando alguma biblioteca de scroll em especifica? Ou qual a versão do Firefox que você precise que funcione ?